# Function SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created the following function yesterday, and now I am facing an error:

> *Invalid length parameter passed to the left or substring function*

Could you guys have a look at my function?I really appreciate it.

```
Create function nowFunctionNewadd
      (@fladd varchar(255))
returns  @tbl table(addr varchar(100), city varchar(100),
                    state varchar(100), Zip varchar(5)) 
as
begin
   declare @str varchar(100)
      ,@i int
      ,@j int
      ,@str2 varchar(100)
      ,@address varchar(100)
      ,@city varchar(100)
      ,@lastcomma int
      ,@lastPart varchar(100)
      ,@zipstart int
      ,@zip varchar(5) = ''

   select @str=rtrim(ltrim(@fladd))

   set @i = charindex(',', @str)
   set @str2=rtrim(ltrim(substring(@str, @i+1, 999)))
   set @j=CHARINDEX(',',@str2)

   set @lastcomma = len(@str) - charindex(',', reverse(@str)+',')
   set @lastPart = substring(@str, @lastcomma+2, 100)
   set @address = REPLACE(rtrim(ltrim(substring(@str,1,@i-1))),',','')
   set @zipstart = patindex('%[0-9]%', @lastpart)
   set @city=LTRIM(RTRIM(substring(@str, @i+1, @j-1)))

   If @zipstart > 0 
      select @zip = substring(@lastpart, @zipstart, 5), 
             @lastPart = rtrim(substring(@lastpart, 1, @zipstart-1))

   insert into @tbl(addr, city, state, Zip)
   values(@address, @city, @lastpart, @zip)

   return
end
```

Comment: Hey guys  it looks like I found my own medicne.I just added  if len(@str)> 0....I  apprecite any additional logic.Once again I am very thankful guys

Comment: Nope..I take it back..I have not found my medicine,no error but,it brings Null .But there are records which I should have.Once again guys I appreciate your suggestions.Thanks again

Comment: can you post some sample data that you are sending into the function?

Comment: '1234 S.Alameda way,LA,CA12345'   Thanks@bluefeet

Comment: is that the line that throws the error?  Do you know what record throws the error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem that I can see with your function starts with this line:

```
set @j=CHARINDEX(',',@str2)
```

And then I am guessing that the error is being thrown by this line:

```
set @city=LTRIM(RTRIM(substring(@str, @i+1, @j-1)))
```

Your function is working under the assumption that you will have more than one comma present in the string value that you are passing.  But if you don't have more than one comma the value for `@j` will be zero and then you are trying to use a `-1` as the length of the city and this will fail throwing the error you are getting.

I created a SQL Fiddle with a demo to work with. Using the address `'1234 S.Alameda way,LA,CA12345'` your function will work.

But if you change the value to  `'1234 S.Alameda way,LACA12345'` it will fail

See [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5983)

Do you know what the format is going to be for all of the values that you need to pass into the function?  If this format is going to change from 1 to 2 or even 3 commas I think you need to rethink how this function is written because it will not work as expected.